# How can I replace this unusual kitchen sink drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing, sink, pipe, drain, drain-waste-vent

I'm trying to replace a broken 1-1/2 inch L-shaped brass pipe under my kitchen sink, as in this picture:

[image: The pipe being replaced]

At one end, it's connected to the sink drain, which if I'm understanding the terminology correctly means this would be called a tailpiece. At the very least, it has the same connection on the end as a tailpiece.

At the other end, it has what I believe is called a slip joint - the pipe goes an inch or two into the pipe it connects to.

When I search for "tailpiece" on any plumbing supplies site, I find pipes that have the right connector, but only straight ones. When I search for elbow pipes, I can't find any pipe with the right connections on each end: tailpipe-type connection at one end, and a slip joint connection at the other.

Even if I found one that was close, there doesn't seem to be any room to add a vertical slip joint, so does that mean I'll need to find a pipe that's *exactly* the right length to begin with?

Comment: I wonder and hope on looking upon the pictures there is a p-trap in this waste line to stop sewer gas. Sewer gas is dangerous in many ways and why we always have p-traps in waste lines, generally but not always they have a clean out at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call it a slip x spigot brass drain street ell. Can't say I've seen one until now. More common is the double slip brass drain ell. Hard to say from a photo, but looks like a short horizontal straight piece could be inserted if you had to use a double slip ell. Perhaps the trap U could be rotated away a bit to buy a little extra distance for this.

Comment: That sounds about right. I assume that by "spigot" you mean the connection that screws on to the sink drain? I found an ell just like the one that was in there - whatever it's called - with the drain connection on top, but way too long horizontally so it had to be cut. Works great!

Comment: Good find, glad it all worked out. Nomenclature on these things is a bit confusing. A slip end is the part with a ring nut that makes a compression connection. With glued connections, 'slip' is the hub end that accepts smooth pipe. Similar portions in function, but makes more sense with glued connections. So a 'spigot' end is the part of a fitting that would normally be the straight smooth pipe portion of a connection, except in this case it is part of the fitting to save room and joints. On further investigation, your piece is apparently a slip x spigot brass waste bend. Close but not quite.

Answer (score 2):

very easy fix,    just cut the pip from the water under kitchen sink, start fresh.
remove all drains,
you need:  1 two part waste      1 trap kit   1 no-hup 1"1/2 to 1"1/2 tuppler and ask for an under sink AC adopter to connect the hose to your garbage disposal to.

very easy, but maybe YouTube might have some photo to show you.
also i advise you to use brass parts, and make sure you have a copper cutter big enough to cut pipes to size, but you will new a saw to cut drain under sink.

i hope this helps :)